# Simplify if-statements in PHP

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Is it possible to simplify a series of `if` statements in PHP that I use to build a URL parameter? And how would I add a `?` before the first parameter, and `&` to the rest, given that `$var1` might be `0` too?

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
<?php 
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 1;
$var3 = 0;
$var4 = 1;

$urlparam = "";
if ($var1 == 1) $urlparam = $urlparam . "?var1=".$var1;
if ($var2 == 1) $urlparam = $urlparam . "&var2=".$var2;
if ($var3 == 1) $urlparam = $urlparam . "&var3=".$var3;
if ($var4 == 1) $urlparam = $urlparam . "&var4=".$var4;

echo "http://example.com/index.php" . $urlparam;
// http://example.com/index.php?var1=1&var2=1&var4=1
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$vars = array(
    'var1' => 1,
    'var2' => 1,
    'var3' => 0,
    'var4' => 1
);
$vars = array_filter($vars);
$urlparam = '?' . http_build_query($vars);
```

1. `$vars` holds an array of the values we may want to put in our querystring
2. [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) removes any with a zero (false) value
3. Use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build our querystring for us using the remaining values

Comment: Excelent, that's exactly what I need. I wasn't aware of the `http_build_query()` function.